should I make every element clear in the claims?
I stated in the description that the strap is not necessarily FLAT, could this statement will be used in the infringement litigation when someone used a angle strap like below.
Or I have to clearly specify it in the claims how the FLAT version and Angle/Bended Version strap works? the embodiment is ONLY a FLAT strap example, is it enough for protection?
the examiner didn't notice it so far.


@GeorgeWhite Well, to be fair, it is unlikely that any particular patent application will be valuable. I don't know how accurate this figure is but some say only 3% of patents become profitable (sounds incredible to me even since I would expect even lower).

@geoagewhite, I am sorry but it has nothing to do with this question.

I would need a clearer explanation to attempt to be helpful. You might not want to make more details public but, as is, I don’t understand the question.

I deleted my unhelpful comment. Thanks.


I stated in the description that the strap is not necessarily FLAT, could this statement will be used in the infringement litigation when someone used a angle strap like below.

It depends on what's in the claim. It sounds like you could claim "strap" or "flat strap". You can't claim "angled strap" because you didn't say "angled". Since, "not flat" could, for example, mean curved (but not angled).
If you claim just "strap" (without "flat") that should also cover angled, provided the description does not somehow contradict angled.
Of course, besides infringement one must also consider anticipation and obviousness. Claiming just "strap" presumably risks invalidity on a broader base of possible prior art than "flat strap". OTOH, while I don't know the application, it is possible that flatness of the strap does not add much in terms of the unobviousness of it. In the latter case it is probably best stake everything on just "strap" (or perhaps to make flatness of the strap a dependent claim).

Or I have to clearly specify it in the claims how the FLAT version and Angle/Bended Version strap works?

If I understood the scenario correctly, you will likely run into written description problems ("new matter") if you try to claim angled or bended. Note also the "bended" means it is the result of having been bent which goes more to the manufacturing method than the shape. Consider other terms for describing the shape.

Hi, @bhuff36,  I hope you are well, thank you for all your support and kindness, I was told my claims is indefinite and unclear, I understand the examiner's impatience when reading a patent application from an unprofessional applicant.

@cmabill Yes, unfortunately it won't cut any ice that you are non-professional/inexperienced. The public is entitled to know with reasonable accuracy what the boundaries of every issued patent are. Hopefully the examiner has indicated why they believe the claims do not meet the definiteness standard, which might give you something to go on (or dispute).
